# useQuery returning undefined in the console but actually making the request in the network tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I am new to react-query and not sure where this issue is coming from.

I am making two different requests in different files, one request to get all users, and the second request fires when the user button is clicked, to get the detail of that particular user. I am setting the userID correctly, when I check the network tab, the request is actually being made and the response returned but when I console the response on my console, I get undefined and then not able to display the data on my browser.

I think its a minor issues but can't figure it out, as I see the response of the data on my network tab. for instance, `Request URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1` returned.

UserDetails.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import * as api from "./UserApi";

const UserDetails = ({ userID }) => {
  const { data: user, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ["user", userID],
    () => api.getUser(userID),
    { enabled: Boolean(userID) }
  );

  console.log("userDetails", user); // returns undefined instead of the data

  if (!userID) {
    return "select a user";
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return "Loading User Detail";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User Details</h1>
      <h4>{user?.name}</h4>
      <h4>{user?.email}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserDetails;
```

UserAPI.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({  
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
});

export const getUser = (id) => {
  api.get(`/users/${id}`).then((response) => response.data);
};
```

App.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Users from "./Users";
import UserDetails from "./UserDetails";

function App() {
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="section1">
        <Users setUserID={setUserID} />
      </div>
      <div className="section2">
        <UserDetails userID={userID} />
        {userID}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You forgot to add `return` here `api.get(`/users/${id}`).then((response) => response.data);` should be `return api.get(`/users/${id}`).then((response) => response.data);` Sorry, formatting is messed up, but you get the point :)

Comment: Thanks so much, I totally forgot that and didn't even notice till you made mention of it.

Thank you, the solution worked just perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue from @Danila comment.

I omitted the return keyword in the getUser function.

This is wrong

```
export const getUser = (id) => {
  api.get(`/users/${id}`).then((response) => response.data);
};
```

This is correct

```
export const getUser = (id) => {
  return api.get(`/users/${id}`).then((response) => response.data);
};
```

As shown, the response has just been returned.